# how to reload data without refreshing page with pagination

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, pagination

i do have the code below, and im trying to update the data without refreshing the page with pagination. i have tried many thing taken from stackoverflow but not succeeded.

PHP--

```
<?php
$auth_id = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['id']);
$auths_id = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['id']);
/**
 * @link: http://www.Awcore.com/dev
 */
    //connect to the database
    include_once ('db/config_books.php'); 
    //get the function
    include_once ('includes/function_ulema.php');



        $page = (int) (!isset($_GET["page"]) ? 1 : $_GET["page"]);
        $limit = 5;
        $startpoint = ($page * $limit) - $limit;

        //to make pagination
        $statement = "books b LEFT OUTER JOIN authors_compile_rel ar ON (b.id = ar.book_id)
        where b.status = 1 AND ( b.auth_id = '".$auth_id."' OR b.t_auth_id = '".$auth_id."' OR ar.auth_id = '".$auth_id."' )";
?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">

<head>
    <title>Pagination</title>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <link href="css/pagination_ulema.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="css/grey_ulema.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

    <style type="text/css">
        .records {
            width: 510px;
            margin: 5px;
            padding:2px 5px;
            border:1px solid #B6B6B6;
        }

        .record {
            color: #474747;
            margin: 5px 0;
            padding: 3px 5px;
            background:#E6E6E6;  
            border: 1px solid #B6B6B6;
            cursor: pointer;
            letter-spacing: 2px;
        }
        .record:hover {
            background:#D3D2D2;
        }


        .round {
            -moz-border-radius:8px;
            -khtml-border-radius: 8px;
            -webkit-border-radius: 8px;
            border-radius:8px;    
        }    
    </style> 
</head>

<body>

    <div class="records round">

        <?php
            //show records
            $query = mysql_query("
SELECT 
b.id, b.unique_name, b.native_name, b.auth_id, b.status, b.create_date, ar.auth_id 
FROM books b LEFT OUTER JOIN authors_compile_rel ar ON (b.id = ar.book_id)
WHERE 
b.status = 1 AND ( b.auth_id = ".$auth_id." OR b.t_auth_id = ".$auth_id." OR ar.auth_id = ".$auth_id." )
ORDER by b.id DESC 
            LIMIT {$startpoint} , {$limit}");

            while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {
        ?>
            <div class="record round"><?php echo $row['id']; echo " - "; echo $row['unique_name']; ?></div>
        <?php    
            }
        ?>
    </div>

<?php
    echo pagination($statement,$limit,$page);
?>

</body>
</html>
```

and i do have the function file of pagination below:

```
<?php
$auth_id = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['id']);
$auths_id = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['id']);
/**
 * @link: http://www.Awcore.com/dev
 */

   function pagination($query, $per_page = 10,$page = 1, $url = '?' ){        
        $query = "SELECT COUNT(*) as `num` FROM {$query}";
        $row = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query($query));
        $total = $row['num'];
        $auth_ids   =   $row['auth_id'];
        $adjacents = "2"; 

        $page = ($page == 0 ? 1 : $page);  
        $start = ($page - 1) * $per_page;                               

        $prev = $page - 1;                          
        $next = $page + 1;
        $lastpage = ceil($total/$per_page);
        $lpm1 = $lastpage - 1;

        $pagination = "";
        if($lastpage > 1)
        {   
            $pagination .= "<ul class='pagination'>";
                    $pagination .= "<li class='details'>Page $page of $lastpage</li>";
            if ($lastpage < 7 + ($adjacents * 2))
            {   
                for ($counter = 1; $counter <= $lastpage; $counter++)
                {
                    if ($counter == $page)
                        $pagination.= "<li><a class='current'>$counter</a></li>";
                    else
                        $pagination.= "<li><a href='{$url}page=$counter&id={$_GET['id']}'>$counter</a></li>";                   
                }
            }
            elseif($lastpage > 5 + ($adjacents * 2))
            {

                if($page < 1 + ($adjacents * 2))        
                {
                    for ($counter = 1; $counter < 4 + ($adjacents * 2); $counter++)
                    {
                        if ($counter == $page)
                            $pagination.= "<li><a class='current'>$counter</a></li>";
                        else
                            $pagination.= "<li><a href='{$url}page=$counter&id={$_GET['id']}'>$counter</a></li>";                   
                    }
                    $pagination.= "<li class='dot'>...</li>";
                    $pagination.= "<li><a href='{$url}page=$lpm1&id={$_GET['id']}'>$lpm1</a></li>";
                    $pagination.= "<li><a href='{$url}page=$lastpage&id={$_GET['id']}'>$lastpage</a></li>";     
                }
                elseif($lastpage - ($adjacents * 2) > $page && $page > ($adjacents * 2))
                {
                    $pagination.= "<li><a href='{$url}page=1&id={$_GET['id']}'>1</a></li>";
                    $pagination.= "<li><a href='{$url}page=2&id={$_GET['id']}'>2</a></li>";
                    $pagination.= "<li class='dot'>...</li>";
                    for ($counter = $page - $adjacents; $counter <= $page + $adjacents; $counter++)
                    {
                        if ($counter == $page)
                            $pagination.= "<li><a class='current'>$counter</a></li>";
                        else
                            $pagination.= "<li><a href='{$url}page=$counter&id={$_GET['id']}'>$counter</a></li>";                   
                    }
                    $pagination.= "<li class='dot'>..</li>";
                    $pagination.= "<li><a href='{$url}page=$lpm1&id={$_GET['id']}'>$lpm1</a></li>";
                    $pagination.= "<li><a href='{$url}page=$lastpage&id={$_GET['id']}'>$lastpage</a></li>";     
                }
                else
                {
                    $pagination.= "<li><a href='{$url}page=1&id={$_GET['id']}'>1</a></li>";
                    $pagination.= "<li><a href='{$url}page=2&id={$_GET['id']}'>2</a></li>";
                    $pagination.= "<li class='dot'>..</li>";
                    for ($counter = $lastpage - (2 + ($adjacents * 2)); $counter <= $lastpage; $counter++)
                    {
                        if ($counter == $page)
                            $pagination.= "<li><a class='current'>$counter</a></li>";
                        else
                            $pagination.= "<li><a href='{$url}page=$counter&id={$_GET['id']}'>$counter</a></li>";                   
                    }
                }
            }

            if ($page < $counter - 1){ 
                $pagination.= "<li><a href='{$url}page=$next&id={$_GET['id']}'>Next</a></li>";
                $pagination.= "<li><a href='{$url}page=$lastpage&id={$_GET['id']}'>Last</a></li>";
            }else{
                $pagination.= "<li><a class='current'>Next</a></li>";
                $pagination.= "<li><a class='current'>Last</a></li>";
            }
            $pagination.= "</ul>\n";        
        }


        return $pagination;
    } 
?>
```

Please help me with integration of the javascript to load the data with pagination without refreshing page.

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is called Ajax. Take a look here: http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/ajax_intro.asp
When a user clicks on a next page you could catch that action with JS and push the selected page to your Ajax script which then calculates an offset for the new data to load. Is that the answer you are looking for or are you looking for code?